# How to check a WinForm's System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs in a subroutine

Tags: vb.net, winforms

`FMECA` is a class and it has `m_fmecaWin` which is a [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) as its member.

In a particular subroutine, I have an object of `FMECA` class and I need to access `m_fmecaWin`'s system event.

```
    Private Sub initialiseFMECATableFromLoad(ByVal fmeca As GraphFMECA, ByVal detTable As DataTable)

        fmeca.m_fmecaWin.chkListBox.AllowGrayed = False
        ' need to mark e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs; e.Cancel = True ' to be reviewed later 

        If fmeca.m_fmecaWin.chkListBox.Items.Count <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each col As GridColumn In fmeca.m_fmecaWin.GridView1.Columns
            fmeca.m_fmecaWin.chkListBox.Items.Add(col.FieldName, col.Caption, CheckState.Checked, True)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Do you think is it possible to access `m_fmeca`'s `FormClosingEventArgs` in the subroutine above?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us why you would want to access that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just handle the closing event here in your routine?

```
AddHandler fmeca.m_fmecaWin.FormClosing, Sub (sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) e.Cancel = True
```

My VB Lambdas might be a little rusty... but I think that syntax is right...